# Flutter: Navigator.push recursion and keep appbar and bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, recursion, navigator

I want to show dynamic listview according to a tree hierarchy.

[image]

What I planned was this : draw listview according to a List with Maps in it,
and when I tap on one item, draw the same listview but with the children's List (to form a tree).

This is the json file

```dart
[{
   "label":"All",
   "children":[
      {
         "label":"test1",
         "children":[
            {
               "label":"test1-1"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "label":"test2"
      },
      {
         "label":"test3"
      }
   ]
}]
```

So, the first page shows one listTile with "All".
If i click on "All", then now there are 3 listTile with "test1", "test2", "test3".

I tried `Navigator.push( ...()=>Scaffold(body: MyPage()))` but of course because it is a new Scaffold, I can't see the bottom navigation bar.

I tried to do it like `Navigator.push(...()=>CurrentClass())` but then flutter says that I don't have a Material to draw on.

How can I fix this?

```dart
return ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              print(_children[index]["children"]);
              List<Map<String, dynamic>> _childMaps =
                  _children[index]["children"];

              return ListTile(
                title: Text(_children[index]["label"]),
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  PageRouteBuilder(
                    pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => Scaffold(
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        title: Text(_children[index]["label"]),
                      ),
                      body: TempScreen(
                        childMaps: _childMaps,
                      ),
                    ),
                    transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                    reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(),
            itemCount: _children.length,
          )
```

Comment: You can create another widget as wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way, using new `MaterialApp` which will push new routes on top of that area and preserve the same `bottomSheet` (navigation) across all of them. Just keep in mind that if you will at some point need to push completely new screen from one of your `subScreens` it will be a little bit tricky.

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        // use new MaterialApp to push new (sub)screens on top of that area and preserve the same bottomSheet (navigation)
        body: const MaterialApp(home: Body()),
        bottomSheet: Container(
          height: 60,
          color: Colors.amber,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: const [
              Icon(Icons.home),
              Icon(Icons.person),
              Icon(Icons.shop),
              Icon(Icons.more),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(.6),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListItem(i),
          itemCount: 5,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const SubScreen(
    this.index, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // just simulating different number of children
    final count = Random().nextInt(7);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('item $index')),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(.6),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ListItem(i),
          itemCount: count,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const ListItem(
    this.index, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SubScreen(index)),
        ),
        title: Text('item $index'),
        tileColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```